# Serial downvoting under the radar?

Tags: support, downvotes, tactical-downvoting

I have a whopping six (6) questions on Stack Overflow.  For a long time, nobody seemed to look at them at all, but now over the last week, five of them have received a downvote.

[image: Observe the -2:s]

I flagged one of them for moderator attention when the first batch came in, but it's visible as "pending" in my [flag history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/874188) (the link is probably restricted to myself and moderators or perhaps only the site admins).  I'm thinking without context, this may be too obscure; so I'm posting here to be able to provide some context.

I find it rather suspicious that unrelated questions which went unnoticed for [months](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12589522/timeline) [or](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34014561/timeline) [even](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31066557/timeline) [for](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27562424/timeline) [over a year](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11789650/timeline) would all coincidentally collect downvotes all at once.  (They [missed one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28317081/timeline), though!)
<sub>(Links are to the useful but obscure [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270438/shouldnt-the-timeline-view-show-votes-that-have-been-removed#comment876313_270438) for each question.)</sub>

I speculate that I have too few questions to pass criteria for "obvious" serial downvoting; but 5/6 I think is pretty compelling, if however circumstancial evidence.

I fairly regularly spend some time looking for off-topic stuff which should not be on the site, and sometimes leave a comment when I nominate something for closing.  Recently, there was one OP in particular who seemed upset (just about a downvote, not actually a close nomination), but this is obviously a quite speculative train of thought at this point ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246550/why-does-easy-install-not-provide-search-capabilities?noredirect=1#comment58207050_35246550) but you need >10k rep to see it).

I don't particularly fret over losing 10 reputation points (and in fact, I agree that at least one of those questions should probably be closed, actually), but I'm hoping to learn more about what measures are in place for what could be an evasion technique for staying under the radar of the automated checks.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: First 4 downvoted within 2 minutes, surely _that_ would get picked up by the script? Looks like obvious serial downvoting to the untrained eye _(that would be me)_

Comment: If various different people (sockouppets ?) downoted your questions, it wouldn't be picked up by the serial-voting-reversal script. Using multiple sockpuppets just to downvote you seems unlikely though..

Comment: The flag queue is pretty backed-up right now, you'll have to give them time to get to it.  Fwiw, you can give the mods less work to do by just voting and not explaining why you voted.  In general SO users already know their question sucks.

Comment: "what measures are in place for what could be an evasion technique for staying under the radar of the automated checks" That's where we come in.

Comment: lol, this has happened several times to me - pairs of downvotes. applied within the same minute. on old, dead questions.  I can't be assed to formally complain to mods about it.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think it's fair to say "in general SO users already know their question sucks."  I tend to comment when users are posting their first question and genuinely seem to have missed reading the intro. I agree that silently downvoting should be the norm, especially if it's clear that OP knows the site but can't be bothered to get their act together when asking a question.

Comment: It takes time (and painful experiences) to recognize the patterns, but there are particular types of questions, work orders for example, where its just best to not comment at all; if not to prevent a hate response, to prevent someone latching on to you like a leech for dear life. however I like the approach that many people take, and that is to comment but not go into details. Just a "welcome to stackoverflow, to get better help sooner consider reading the help center and taking the tour" kind of friendly neutral feedback. And then downvote with a big smile.

Comment: Nobody does anything about serial downvoting. I've suffered 3 nights of clear serial downvoting in the past week. I flagged the posts, used the contact us link, and prayed to the almighty automated nightly script (which I no longer believe exists). Nothing. Maybe if you can bribe a SO employee to reveal the username and IP of the serial downvoter you can identify them and hire a gang member to assassinate them. That's my current plan.

Comment: @JonasCz It happens all the time

Comment: I just had the same issue: 6 of my posts were downvoted in 2 minutes. I flagged one of them for moderator attention and guess what: after a few hours, I got reversal + _user deletion_ from the guy who downvoted! The catch is: the guy upvoted me once (WTF, just keep doing that !!) so I gained back +12-10 = 2. But I'm glad because I had a lot of 0 and -1 marks on my posts whereas the answers where OK. So thumbs ups mods!!