# Why was my custom flag about serial downvoting declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, serial-voting

I recently raised a custom moderator flag about the flood of downvotes I am getting recently. While I had raised one before, the downvotes were reversed by the downvoter and replaced by upvotes, so I thought another user targeted me.

I wouldn't personally like to post the test in the custom flag, however, I will just sum up.

I mentioned that the downvoter downvoted 3 of my posts on Jun 12, but, this time, they did, with some 1 minute difference between each vote (total three). Also, I said that there were 2 more downvotes from Jun 11, which weren't reversed, possibly by the same downvoter, since the reversal script reversed up to 3 votes, as I have been told. At the end, I requested the case to be escalated to the CMs, since it was not the first nor the last time it happens (I admit I made a typo in the original flag text and wrote no**t** and not no**r**, but I don't).

I was surprised because the moderator who declined the flag didn't leave a comment, but a canned reason, so, if my flag was declined correctly, what was wrong with it? Did a CM review it and found that there were actually two or more people that downvoted me?

Comment: @weegee OP says the script ran but didn't reverse 2 of the down votes. They want to know why the flag about the two unreversed votes was declined.

Comment: @weegee I'm pretty sure the general idea is the batches. I count at least 3, and I think the flag is an attempt to raise attention to a repeated pattern of abuse, not just this specific instance (see the [3 -6'es here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10607772/double-beep?tab=reputation))

Comment: The OP did flag for moderation attention but got declined. What we can conclude from that is that they (moderators) didn't have enough evidence to support that this was actual serial downvoting or maybe a mistake from their end as it doesn't include any reason for the decline

Comment: @weegee huh? Moderators usually don't handle these cases their own - they can't actually to say/see if someone is being serially downvoted - only CMs and employees can.

Comment: oh yes, we have means to check that, but not in all cases. I suppose the moderator who declned the flag decided that it wasn't worth bothering a CM for 2 or 3 downvotes.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre nah, that's not 2-3 downvotes, that's a whole pattern, which is most likely all from a user. That's mainly what I want to be investigated, not the DVs to be reversed.

Comment: you can also contact the CM team directly ("contact us" link). It's better to go through moderators first, though, in case moderators can do something for you. (note: I'm not the one who declined the flag)

Comment: @weegee I'm not a mod to know what happened firstly and secondly - I don't even know if the mod who declined the flag actually contacted CMs.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks, I prefer mods, because SE will reply in **about** 6 to 8 weeks or so.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre really? That is what is happening? What if a user knows about this system and decides to downvote in an irregular pattern or in a period of a long time to tackle this system from ever running. Mods will see that there are just x number of downvotes and move on?

Comment: if the votes were to be reversed, the CMs would have to be in the loop. We cannot reverse the votes (unless we nuke the voting account :)). I'll try to reach out to the mod who declined: I just pinged the mod.

Comment: @weegee I can't really detail what moderators see or not. What they don't see is the user id of the downvoter on each post. CMs can see that. CMs also have a lot on their plates

Comment: What I mean is that the request which the OP made, never reached a CM because the mods made the decision that it's not worth bothering a CM because of just x number of downvotes where x can be any small number of downvotes @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the CMs wouldn't reverse it. It's trivial

Comment: @YvetteColomb I don't really think it's trivial. It happened again in the night and today some 1 hour ago. It is a pattern and not some random individual votes. At least, should I care, now?

Comment: @double-beep I understand what you're going through. Have a look at my rep at [the beginning of the year](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956566/yvette-colomb?tab=reputation&page=2). I used to get upset about this too and it was made clear to me by the community team, not to sweat it. They won't reverse all the votes. Focus on all your upvotes. For as many haters out there, there's always fans or supporters. For clarity mods can see if people are being serial voted.

Comment: I've had another look at your account and the downvotes are not all coming from the same person. If it gets out of hand raise another flag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I handled the flag.

### Not all downvotes are reversed.

You have no record of permanent targeted serial downvoting on your account. Meaning no one person is targeting you excessively.

So the decline reason:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

There's no need to raise a mod flag. Wait 24 hours for the reversal script to run. If we got a flag for everytime someone has two or three downvotes we'd be flooded.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't dare downvote this.

Comment: @JamesKPolk que?

Comment: Just joking. Your explanation was terse and little intimidating.

Comment: @JamesKPolk yeh, my life is like that atm ;)

Comment: @JamesKPolk we have your downvoting record against moderators. We will publish it shortly.

Answer (score 7):

Related question (unanswered): [Serial downvoting under the radar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316567/serial-downvoting-under-the-radar)

I'm not the mod who handled/dismissed the flag but I would have handled it the same way probably (or maybe marking as "helpful" with "sorry can't do more", to avoid getting you a flag decline for this).

You have been downvoted 5 times on june the 11th and 12th

```
2019-06-12 18:31:33     post_downvoted  -2  Batch Script on CMD to get COM port on a variable     ✅
2019-06-12 18:31:29     post_downvoted  -2  possible to run/call a function in a batch file directly from cmd?    ✅
2019-06-12 18:31:07     post_downvoted  -2  This for /r loop works in an unintended way   ✅
2019-06-11 15:43:57     post_downvoted  -2  This for /r loop works in an unintended way   
2019-06-11 15:43:48     post_downvoted  -2  possible to run/call a function in a batch file directly from cmd?
```

The serial reversal script reverted the 3 downvotes above, but left the 2 downvotes from june 11th probably because there are not enough votes in a row to justify reversal *even if the same user downvoted you in 9 seconds* (which cannot be established right now)

now you had 3 downvotes again:

```
2019-06-14 15:02:15     post_downvoted  -2  How can I add multiple if else conditions for choice parameter?   
2019-06-14 14:59:57     post_downvoted  -2  Find current console size in batch    
2019-06-14 14:59:13     post_downvoted  -2  What is 'nul' in batch file?
```

Which doesn't seem to have been reversed, maybe because the last vote was a bit later.

I didn't write the script or even know how it works, but I suppose that it first checks the downvoting times and discards the votes too far for one another. It only checks the ID of the person afterwards, probably because it's a costly/sensitive operation.

Now why the moderator declined your flag (or would have declined it) ?

The moderator probably estimated that:

- 2 downvotes is not worth bothering the community managers (when it could very well be 2 downvotes by different users, yes it happens). I don't know tools they have but I suppose that it's tedious to do such investigations. So it's better be worth it.
- if the same user continues downvoting you, we'll be able to detect it, even if the votes are spread on a long time period.

Maybe the moderator didn't want to expose the investigation method too much, or didn't have time to answer with a non-canned response. But even if they responded, they could only have told you:

> sorry, there's no evidence that the 2 remaining downvotes are from the same person

which is not a great improvement over:

> a moderator reviewed your flag but found no evidence to support it

Moreover, the less we provide details about the means we have to detect those fraudulent activities the more efficient we are (yes, security by obscurity, I know)

Now, maybe the flag should have been marked "helpful". But apart from that, the result would have been the same.

So if that continues, flag again. My personal experience:

- I had 3 downvotes manually reverted a long time ago after flagging.
- I also had 6 downvotes reverted after user deletion after a flagging (but maybe this user was a fraud too)
- I also had some declined flags on 2 downvotes (yeah, I know it's frustrating, but I got the rep back by asking/answering more questions)

We spend a lot of time trying to catch sock pupetteers / cheaters / serial voters. If the person keeps downvoting you, we'll catch that, and have all their votes against you invalidated by contacting the community managers with concrete information.

Comment: *I got the rep back by asking/answering more questions* that cuts in more ways, as it might demotivate the serial downvoter as well, seeing their attacks have no lasting effect.

Comment: true, and as I said, the serial downvoter is likely to get caught if they continue. The only annoying thing is that it artificially changes the post score, so future viewers may think it's worse that it's actually is