# Serial downvoting imperfectly reversed

Tags: bug, downvotes, serial-voting

My small handful of questions on Stack Overflow rarely get any attention at all. It would then seem pretty obvious that when several get downvoted in relatively rapid succession, all of those downvotes are part of the same serial downvoting incident.

[image: Inbox screenshot, 5 adjacent downvotes]

That was yesterday. This morning, I got an inbox notification that serial downvoting had been reversed:

[image: Inbox screenshot: _three_ of them reversed]

So it seems that the reversal was only partial: the incident comprised five downvotes (5*-2=-10) but the reversal only gave me back three (3*2=6).

I can live with getting only part or even none of the rep back; but I'm wondering if the logic is a little *too* heuristic if it mishandles what seems to be a very cut and dried case.

The two missed ones seem to be

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28317081/timeline#/debug-on-error-vs-debug-on-signal-in-json-el-in-particular
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57285676/timeline#/should-path-contain-directories-or-full-paths-to-binaries

Tangentially see also this previous question of mine: [Serial downvoting under the radar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316567/serial-downvoting-under-the-radar)

Comment: They just used two accounts to vote, only the votes from the one that voted three times were rolled back.  Mods don't mind chasing sock accounts.

Comment: nice paint job on your achievement details.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks *blush*

Comment: Have you eventually resolved your issue? How long did it take between "helpful" flag and actual reversal by the CMs? I'm in the same situation: it's not for the rep, but for my poor THREE questions (very specific and for this reason with no upvotes and sentenced to remain without an answer) that with these downvotes might be deleted by the mods. I'm really frustrated and disappointed. I'm here to _give back_ after years of lurking, to help rather than to ask. But as a victim of tactical downvotes and now of serial downvotes I'm losing all my enthusiasm.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Thanks for asking. I don't *think* it has been reversed but I can't find a good way to search through my rep history for the last three months for another "Voting corrected" event, let alone then a way to establish whether it was related to this incident if I was able to find one.

Comment: Just curious - got 18 downvotes in the last few days. Got 16+20 points of "serial downvoting revoted" - so it seems its been delt with. Do serial downvoter get  voting privs revoked or do I have to fear thats going to continue?

Comment: Probably ask a separate question if you need an authoritative answer from a mod or employee. My impression is that there will be a penalty and I would presume the perpetrator's further actions will be scrutinized closely if they are not suspended entirely. (A suspended account it more likely to be abandoned so letting them keep their privileges might be an easier solution than having to be prepared for them to reappear with a new account.)

Answer (score 9):

You can raise a mod-flag on one of the posts. I had a similar situation a couple of months ago. There were reversed by a CM

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I custom mod flagged both with a link back here.

Comment: CM can see exactly who voted. It's very likely that the one who did that is identified. The mod flag will have to be escalated to them in that case, but yes, that's the thing to do and we usually follow in cases like this.

Comment: That's on page *55* of your flag history. You went back and dug that up just as evidence to answer this question? That's dedication.

Comment: @CodyGray Please  Stop  Exposing  Me.

Comment: I also had flagged similar situation on 6 Oct, around a month ago and the flag was marked as helpful, but still waiting for a reversal by CM team

Comment: CMs have a lot on their plate. It takes forever, we know... Be patient. After all it's just internet points. My strategy is: when I get downvoted, it gives me more energy to get a question and answer it, generally getting me some more rep.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what consequences do serial DV-ters face? Ban? Suspension? IMO someone who serial DV should be seriously punished. It is worse than a bit to nervous discussion

Comment: It depends on the moderator, but in general, the first revenge downvoting offence just gets you a warning. The second one gets you a 7-day suspension, and it increases until the user is suspended till new century.

Comment: Does that mean I can also flag the posts the reversing system missed (4) ?